# Not able to Login in Next js app in production

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

I deployed an Next.js web app on Vercel. And my website is working fine but when i try to login it never send the request to api and get back the session details but it never log in in the app. I am a beginner not able to find why, please look at it!

**pages/api/current.ts**

```
import serverAuth from "@/libs/severAuth";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method !== "GET") {
    return res.status(404).end();
  }
  try {
    const { currentUser } = await serverAuth(req);
    return res.status(200).json(currentUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).end();
  }
}

export default handler;
```

**@/libs/severAuth.ts**

```
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

import prisma from "@/libs/prismadb";

const serverAuth = async (req: NextApiRequest) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session?.user?.email) {
    throw new Error("Not signed in");
  }

  const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: session.user.email,
    },
  });

  if (!currentUser) {
    throw new Error("Not signed in");
  }

  return { currentUser };
};

export default serverAuth;
```

**@/libs/prismadb.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

const client = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = client;

export default client;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "x-twitter-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && prisma generate",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.5.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "swr": "^2.2.4",
    "zustand": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.5.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.5.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

[Before Login :-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tzc1.png)
[After Login :-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngrfR.png)

Expecting results after login[here i am logged in , but this is in my laptop in localhost server not in vercel server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIbAr.png) :-